# SQL Server 2014 - How to calculate percentage based on last NOT NULL value in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table `dates`, `items` and `sales` as show below :

table **Dates** :

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| Date_ID | StartDates | EndDates   |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 1       | 2016-07-01 | 2016-07-05 |
| 2       | 2016-07-06 | 2016-07-12 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

table **items** :

```
+--------+----------+---------+
| ITM_ID | ITM_Name | ITM_Qty |
+--------+----------+---------+
| A0001  | Item A   | 30      |
| B0001  | Item B   | 50      |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

table **sales** :

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Sales_ID | Sales_Date | Sales_Item | Sales_Qty |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| S0001    | 2016-07-02 | A          | 5         |
| S0002    | 2016-07-04 | A          | 15        |
| S0003    | 2016-07-08 | B          | 20        |
| S0004    | 2016-07-12 | A          | 10        |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I would like to calculate a percentage (act like a ratio of sales on current period compared to the previous period) and the available amount of item after each sales.

My expected output would be like this :

```
+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
| StartDates | EndDates   | Item_ID | Sold_Qty | Percents | Available |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 2016-07-01 | 2016-07-05 | A0001   | 20       | 100      | 10        |
| 2016-07-01 | 2016-07-05 | B0001   | 0        | 0        | 50        |
| 2016-07-06 | 2016-07-12 | A0001   | 10       | 50       | 0         |
| 2016-07-06 | 2016-07-12 | B0001   | 20       | 100      | 30        |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

I hope the expected output will be possible but I have currently not get a working query yet.

As the table above, the column `percents` is a percentage sales of current period compared to the last period, i.e. on item `A0001` first period has `sold_qty` is 20 and the second period is 10, therefore the percentage of second period is (10/20) * 100 = 50.

**EDIT** : for the case of item `B0001`, the `sold_qty` of the first period is 0, therefore the percentage count should not consider the value on the first period.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below. For Calculating Percents i have used case statement that you can simplify it based on your requirement.

```
  SELECT *,
           CASE
             WHEN SOLD_QTY = 0 THEN 0
             WHEN LAG(SOLD_QTY)
                    OVER(
                      PARTITION BY ITM_ID
                      ORDER BY ITM_ID) = 0
                   OR LAG(SOLD_QTY)
                        OVER(
                          PARTITION BY ITM_ID
                          ORDER BY ITM_ID) IS NULL THEN 100
             ELSE CONVERT(FLOAT, SOLD_QTY) / NULLIF(LAG(SOLD_QTY)
                                                      OVER(
                                                        PARTITION BY ITM_ID
                                                        ORDER BY ITM_ID), 0) * 100
           END PERCENTS
    FROM   (SELECT T1.STARTDATES,
                   T1.ENDDATES,
                   T2.ITM_ID,
                   ISNULL(SUM(T3.SALES_QTY), 0)                   SOLD_QTY,
                   ( T2.[ITM_QTY] ) - ISNULL(SUM(T3.SALES_QTY), 0)AS AVIL
            FROM   #TABLE1 T1
                   CROSS JOIN #TABLE2 T2
                   LEFT JOIN #TABLE3 T3
                          ON T3.[SALES_ITEM] = LEFT(T2.[ITM_ID], 1)
                             AND T3.SALES_DATE BETWEEN T1.STARTDATES AND T1.ENDDATES
            GROUP  BY T1.STARTDATES,
                      T1.ENDDATES,
                      T2.ITM_ID,
                      T2.[ITM_QTY])A
```